# can the program be terminated early from within a methood

Tags: java

I am making a simple "game" where the user is asked a question and must give the correct answer to move on this is the code I currently have for one of the questions.

```
public static void Mascot() {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("what Is our school mascot?");
    String Tony = console.nextLine();
    String b = Tony;
    Scanner scanner= new Scanner(b);
    if (scanner.hasNext("tiger")){
        System.out.println("Good, next riddle.");
    } else{ 
    }
    scanner.close();
    console.close();
}
```

I want the if statement to be case-insensitive and return true if tiger is input in the scanner at all. like someone could enter a full sentence into the scanner and if the word tiger is anywhere it returns as true. but if tiger (or any other incorrect answer for any other question is input in the scanner, I want the program to stop. and not continue to the next question.

Comment: What are the multiple questions and from where you would get other questions?

Comment: You can have a boolean flag as a condition in while loop. Read until tiger is there from input, if its not, then make the flag false. You will come out of loop, and it will not read further.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things to note here.

1. Whether to continue the game or not should ideally be controlled by the caller of the method. The caller of the method should decide based on the return value true or false
2. To accommodate (1) method signature needs to change. It can't be void. It should be boolean.
3. You don't need the second scanner object to verify if it contains **tiger**

Please check if this code helps you

```
public static boolean Mascot() {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            System.out.println("what Is our school mascot?");
            String b = console.nextLine();
           
            if (b.toLowerCase().contains("tiger")){
                System.out.println("Good, next riddle.");
                return true;
            } else{
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception Occurred");
        }
        finally {
            console.close();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't wait for input and just immediately says an exception has occurred, then continues the game.